# Self hosted cloud storage

Tags: dropbox, webdav, cloud

I'm looking for some software that would provide features like Dropbox.

Will a simple webdav be enough for this use case?

Comment: Which features in particular are you interested in?

Comment: @cjm Access (optimally as a directory/virtual disk) from all desktop platforms (mobile platforms would be nice). I don't really need any features around user management, just password protection is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[OwnCloud](http://owncloud.org/) is supposed to be a self-hostable cloud solution, see [its feature list](http://owncloud.org/features/).  It indeed offers WebDAV access, but also a lot more.

While building your own solution using WebDAV is probably possible (and its sufficiency heavily depends on your requested features, as @cjm noted), I'd advise to also have a look at [`git-annex`](http://git-annex.branchable.com/) and especially keep an eye on [`git-annex assistant`](http://git-annex.branchable.com/design/assistant/).

Comment: I have installed and test run Own, it does what it advertises, and will provide you with a "Home Cloud Server". (Still prefer my SFTP though!)

Answer (score 0):

NextCloud is self-hosted and opensource based on PHP and a MySQL/MariaDB or SQL-Lite backend - It's a fork of ownCloud however NC does get a more frequent update and larger community supported apps.

Both have a variety of desktop apps and support for mobile apps that are free in the App/Play store

WebDAV is supported and a drive can be mounted with minimal effort, Speaking of Dropbox you also get some neat features such as shares with features like (password protect/time limit / internal-external links/ edit/download/view only, etc..)

Another neat feature is the integration with OpenOffice / Collabera which allows document editing within the browser and multi-user collaboration.

Both options do support pluggable apps - the App store does have plenty of business use cases such as Active Directory integration, Roundcube client, photo editor, music player, or even a kanban board.

A list of features can go on and on for unbeatable price "Free"...